# Retrieving Texts from already existing Database and table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have made a Database and a table which is working fine. Now i wish to retrieve the entered data in the table and display it in TextView . But i am not able to do it. I am sharing the  code and log cat . Please Help

Helper class(Here i referred to the already existing DB):
    package com.example.query;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHElper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

      public DBHElper(Context context) {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

MainActivity(Here i queried the table and displayed it on textview)

```
package com.example.query;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";
     TextView tv;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        QueryDb();
    }

    private void QueryDb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {

        DBHElper helper = new DBHElper(this.getApplicationContext());
        db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT " +
                 TABLE_COMMENTS 
                 , null);

        if(c!=null)
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String comment=c.getString(1);
                    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.labels);
                    tv.setText(comment);
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }


    }catch(SQLiteException se)
    {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

LOGCAT

```
  04-09 16:59:46.460: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1662): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg =   no such column: COLUMN_COMMENT, db=/data/data/com.example.query/databases/commments.db
  04-09 16:59:46.470: E/MainActivity(1662): Could not create or Open the database
  04-09 16:59:46.610: D/gralloc_goldfish(1662): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid. You need to correct it to:

```
String query = "select " + DBHElper.COLUMN_COMMENT + " from "
               + DBHElper.TABLE_COMMENTS;
db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

In your origin query, you wrote:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT " + TABLE_COMMENTS
```

You have a few mistakes:

- You are missing `FROM` clause that is mandatory
- You named column as **comment** and you assigned
  **COLUMN_COMMENT**. This should be correct but you need to assign it to query as variable(that holds column name value) and not as literal.

### Second big mistake:

You forgot to create database. So you have to create database in your `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   String createQuery = "create table " + DBHElper.TABLE_COMMENTS + "("
   + DBHElper.COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
   + DBHElper.COLUMN_COMMENT + " text" + ")";
   db.execSQL(qreateQuery);
}
```

Also i recommend you to implement onUpgrade() method as well:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   String upgradeQuery = "drop table if exists " + DBHElper.TABLE_COMMENTS;
   db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);
   onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: My bad . I corrected it but still no luck  Log CAT: 04-09 17:18:23.040: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1752): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: comments, db=/data/data/com.example.query/databases/commments.db
04-09 17:18:23.040: E/MainActivity(1752): Could not create or Open the database
04-09 17:18:23.170: D/gralloc_goldfish(1752): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: @VishalThakur you forgot to create table, check updated answer.

Comment: But i already have created a table in another project and now i wish to retrieve data from table of that DB

Comment: @VishalThakur you cannot access to database in another project since is stored in internal storage. It's not possible(in this way but correct way is not trivial).

Comment: Oh. Can you please share any example or some resource which i can refer to or if its not possible then can you throw some light over it

Comment: @VishalThakur you cannot connect to database created in another project that is stored in internal storage. its invisible for you. But you can achieve your goal if your db will be stored in SD card. Then you are able to read from db.